# How to put Sencha touch files and run using phonegap in Eclipse?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to work with phone gap. So i build one app in sencha and trying to build using phonegap 1.8 to access native functionality. To setup my eclipse using phonegap..i follow the below links:
[Phonegap Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)

Then inside the www folder i keep my index.html and i keep my app folder inside that. So my folder structure is like this in android project:

```
---src
|   |--package name
|        |---------activity name
|--assets
|     |----www
|          |----app
|          |     |---view
|          |     |      |----Panel.js(Sencha file)
|          |     |---app.js
|          |-----index.html
|          |-----corodova.js
|--libs
    |----corodova.jar
    |----touch
          |----resources
          |      |-----css
          |             |----sencha-touch.css
          |
          |----sencha-touch-debug.js
```

But when i am running it in simulator, it is showing white screen.

Here is my panel.js code

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Panel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',

config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            height: 52,
            title: 'Feedback'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

Here is my index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Auto Generated with Sencha Architect -->
<!-- Modifications to this file will be overwritten. -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Listview</title>
    <script src="libs/touch/sencha-touch-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <link href="libs/touch/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" id="phonegap" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (!Ext.browser.is.WebKit) {
            alert("The current browser is unsupported.\n\nSupported browsers:\n" +
                "Google Chrome\n" +
                "Apple Safari\n" +
                "Mobile Safari (iOS)\n" +
                "Android Browser\n" +
                "BlackBerry Browser"
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

And in activity i wrote the below code:

```
    package com.innominds.cameraApp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class SenchaCameraAPPActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me as i am not able to figure it out. I am new in this phonegap.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can anyone help please..where i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep sencha-touch.css in the same folder as index.html and added the resource folder..

I share the solution in the blog: [Blog URL](http://blogformobile.wordpress.com)

Comment: did u find a solution ? if yes then plz share with me.

Comment: if i check minimal phonegap project while starting it runs properly but when i check phonegap API example with sencha touch 1 then it shows white blank screen.

Comment: @prakash_d22 Sorry for late reply. I share the solution in the blog:  http://blogformobile.wordpress.com....... just check it. Hope it will help you.

Comment: nopes im not getting it. i have installed plugin of phonegap in eclipse .istart by clicking phonegap logo then i check sencha touch 2 and add the code in index .html file its showing a white blank screen

Comment: here is my code  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
   
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="sencha/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" type="text/css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="sencha/sencha-touch.js"></script>
   
   </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
new Ext.Application ({
launch:function(){
 new Ext.Panel({
  fullscreen:true,
  html:"hello satara"
 });
} 
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: its showing following error "connection to the server was unsucessfull.(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)"

Answer (score 1):

When you get the white screen, it is because there is something in your Javascript (probably in your **app.js**), like a missing coma or an undefined variable, function or else.

Try to launch your index.html in Chrome, Safari or Firefox. Then launch the **Web inspector** (usually it is right-click > inspect element). Then go to the console tab and look if there are errors.

Hope this helps

Comment: Now i am getting referenceError..It is not able to find Ext.

Answer (score 1):

include sench-touch.js fiel in head of index.html befor app.js

Comment: I kept sencha-touch-debug.jas and sencha-touch.css inside the libs folder. But i am gertting this errors in the web inspector:: GET file:///E:/Android%20Project/SenchaCameraAPP/assets/www/libs/touch/sencha-touch-debug.js  index.html:9
Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined app.js:16
Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined index.html:14
GET file:///E:/Android%20Project/SenchaCameraAPP/assets/www/libs/touch/resources/css/sencha-touch.css  index.html:9

Comment: show web inspector and confirm that is sencha-touch-debug.js loaded or not,I am saure this probel because of that.

Comment: may be parth u provided is wrong or file is not availabel at location you provided.

Comment: I edited the file structure. Just look on that, and can u tell me where i am doing wrong in index.html file, if u have time.

Comment: you should try by puting sencha-touch-debug.js file same folder as index.html and src='sencha-touch-debug.js'

Comment: Hey i changed sencha-touch-debug.js to sencha-touch-all.js. Now it is coming. But i added panel and toolbar and then i added some text called 'Feedback'. But toolbar is not coming. Only Feedback is showing in the whitescreen

Comment: Hey now it is coming. I keep sencha-touch.css in the same folder like index.html.........and it is coming..

Comment: same problem with me getting white blank screen

Answer (score 0):

see this is my eclipse set up and i have opened the index.html file

[image: error]

Comment: now doing this as per google and other blog instructions i am still getting an error with white blank screen.

Comment: Just follow the steps which i mentioned in the blog. You are installing the MDS and trying, i hope. And you are running in which simulator????

Comment: I tried with that. means with mds applaud. But for me also it is giving me the problem. the white screen. Thats why i am telling you to follow the steps of my blog. Now it is upto you.